# How I can use ng-disable in a iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe, textarea, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have in iframe which I set ng-disable to true, in the iframe I call an html that contains a textarea, but even though the iframe is disabled this control I can access it without any problem.

How or what should be done to disable and enable in run time textarea control within the iframe, using angular?

Comment: Too many unknowns here. Create a **runnable** demo that reproduces issue. You can create iframe content in plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ng-disabled affects with INPUT element only
If you want to disable entire Iframe element you should use a ng-class or ng-show/ng-hide and write a cssClass background cover entire your Iframe to prevent from clicking.

Comment: Can you give me an example?
please.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XPTUujfQquEIVo7yXFJF?p=preview in this example I used ng-show to show/hide `iframe-disable-background` class. you also can use ng-class to toggle class instead